# doctrine2 date/datetime as ID

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

is it possible to set an attribute as an id when the column is date or datetime?`

Here my Attribute in the entity:

```
/**
 * @var date $statisticdate
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="statisticdate", type="date", nullable=false, unique=true)
 * @Id
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $statisticdate;
```

When i'm persisting a new object, i have an error that the object Datetime cannot be converted to string. 
Now i created a normal id attribut and everything works.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you updated the column type in the database to hold a date?

Answer (score 1):

Asfar as I know, it is only allowed in a composite key, and even that is has some known issues. I think the easy solution can be to make it a string and let the setStaticdate($datetime) check wheather it is a valid date or not.